# Reduce the value of a random value of X over incremental increase in the value of Y in Java

Tags: java, math, random, integer, double

I have a bit of a math puzzler on my hands. I have a random value of X, where X is a double (potentially decimal value) that is 0 < x < 20, and an incremental integer value of Y in a loop that for purposed of this question we will cap at 1000.

I want to reduce the value of X by an incremental percentage based on the current value of Y.  Initially I was doing this.  getrand() is an external function that returns a NEW value for X on every iteration of the loop.

```
Integer y = 0;
while (y < 1000)
{
    y = y + 1;
    Double x = getRand();  // any decimal value between 0 and 20
    x = x / y;
    // the value of X,Y then gets plotted on a map
    doPlot(x,y);
}
```

While this works, the initial reduction of X is X / 2, then X / 3.. and so on. I would much prefer a linear(ish) or quadratic curve style reduction of X, that starts off as a small reduction of X and becomes larger as Y grows larger, and X should never be negative.

Keep in mind that X could potentially be a decimal value that is < 1. I still want to reduce it by a percentage.  I've thought of a number of things I could do, but my code got all filled up with conditional statements to check the value of X.

How can I accomplish this in short and efficient Java? Thanks!

To edify - The X value is a **NEW random** double between 0 and 20 on EACH iteration of the loop, it is not a static value.  X could be 0.00000001 or it could be 19.999999

Comment: Your "infinite" loop will overflow your Y (or is it `i`?) after just over 2 billion iterations, after which Y will turn into a very negative number. And what do you mean with "potentially decimal"?

Comment: this is a theoretical question regarding the loop.  And potentially decimal is just that.. X could be 0.000000001 or it could be 19.

Comment: I'm still confused whether your question is a mathematical or a programming question. Theoretical questions don't exist in programming (I didn't say "computer science") as such - you can either program it with real code or not. Is this question perhaps more suited to the Maths StackExchange? http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll fix the question then, this is a programming question. The "infinite" portion of my loop is the theoretical.. in reality the loop is not likely to have more than 100 iterations, the incremental value is very much capped for the application i'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that code doesn't do anything. I get that it's just an example, but it doesn't even do what you're talking about, as X is thrown away every iteration.

Anyway, you need to decide how many timesteps you want your iteration to take (since it's linear), and then subtract by the same amount during each iteration of the loop (instead of dividing by a different number each time). Something like:

```
int timesteps = 10;
double x = getrand();
double subtractEachTime = x/timesteps;
for(int i = 0; i < timesteps; i++)
{
  x -= subtractEachTime;
}
```

Also note that you should make sure x is equal to whatever you actually wanted at the end of the loop, to avoid floating point rounding errors.

This example takes you from a random number down to zero, but it can be generalized to go from any number to any other number. This is called linear interpolation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Comment: X is supposed to be thrown away every iteration, it is a NEW random double between 0 and 20 on EACH iteration. Your answer assumes X is static and is wrong.

Comment: If X is thrown away each time, then your code doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you dont have a clear picture of what you want to do.  Here is a guess at code that will continuously decrease `x` as a function of `(x,i,getRand())`

```
int i = 0;
double x = getrand();
while(true){
    double a_number_less_than_one = getRand()/(i+1)*20;
    x = x/a_number_less_than_one;
    i++;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: once again, assuming X is static..  it is not. X is a NEW double between 0 and 20 on every iteration of the loop. Please re-read the question I am very clear of what I want to do.